# django decimal form field not taking value equal to max_value

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a DecimalField in my form and i would like to restrict `min_value=0.1` and `max_value=99.99`

```
purity_percent = forms.DecimalField(max_value=99.99, min_value=0.1, decimal_places=2)
```

But when i try to enter value equal to `0.1` or `99.99` i will not work i get these error

`For 0.1 : Ensure this value is greater than or equal to 0.1.`

`For 99.99 : Ensure this value is less than or equal to 99.99.`

How to do i include those in the limit too.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Floats, like `99.99`, are stored in binary. Many numbers that can be represented with finite decimal digits are repeating fractions in binary (see many other questions for that).

In particular, the literal `99.99` is closer to:

```
>>> "{:.15f}".format(99.99)
'99.989999999999995'
```

Python also has Decimals:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> d = Decimal("99.99")
```

And sure enough, the Decimal 99.99 is larger than the float max_value 99.99:

```
>>> d <= 99.99
False
```

The Django developers knew about binary and this is the entire reason for the existence of the `DecimalField`: it stores Decimals.

**Conclusion:** Use `Decimal("99.99")` as your max_value, not a float.